# Unable to write to csv file using python

Tags: python, csv

I am try to mark attendance on csv file using python opencv code . The code doesnt show any errors but it is unable to mark attendance in the csv file.

Here is the code

```
def mark_attendance(self,n):
    with open("att.csv","a+",newline="\n",encoding="UTF8") as f:
        myDataList=csv.reader(f)
        nameList=[]
        for line in myDataList:
            entry=line.split((","))
            nameList.append(entry[0])
            if (n not in nameList):
                now=datetime.now()
                d1=now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
                dstring=now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
                f.writelines(f"\n{n},{dtstring},PRESENT")
```

Comment: You should open the file for 'r', read in the whole file, then add your new lines, then open the file for 'w' and write the whole file.  Right now, you're trying to write to the file in the middle of reading it.  That won't work.  You can't change lines in the middle of a file.

Comment: And you don't need to split the line using `split(",")`.  Because you're using the CSV reader, it will already be split into fields.

Comment: And since you're going to be marking many names, you should probably read the whole file, then call `mark_attendance` multiple times, then write out the finished file.

Comment: Can you please write some code for that

Answer (score 0):

This is approximately what you're after.  You had "self" parameters, so you maybe want this as part of a class.  In that case, the "names" list could be a class member.

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime

def read_attendance():
    with open("att.csv","r",encoding="UTF8") as f:
        names = [row for row in csv.reader(f)]
    return names

def write_attendance( names ):
    with open("att.csv", "w") as f:
        wr = csv.writer(f)        
        for row in names:
            wr.writerow(row)

def mark_attendance( names,n  ):
    for row in names:
        if row[0] == n:
            return
    now=datetime.now()
    dstring=now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
    names.append( (n, dstring, "PRESENT") )

def test():
    names = read_attendance()
    mark_attendance( names, "Billy Bob" )
    mark_attendance( names, "Jimmy Joe" )
    mark_attendance( names, "Peggy Sue" )
    write_attendance( names )
```

You could improve this by having `names` be a dictionary with the name as the key.  That way, `mark_attendance` wouldn't have to do a loop, just `if n not in names:`.